# Non-recursive flood filler method

Tags: java, flood-fill, non-recursive

I am making non-recursive flood fill method in Java which uses coordinates of clicked pixel (x,y) and color code as input.       img is buffered image.

Code works, but only for large simple shapes (like squares), and sometimes does not fill even them. How can it be corrected to work always and with any shape?

```
 public void floodFillNoRecursion (int x, int y, int color) {
  if (img.getRGB(x, y)!=Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {  
     return;
     } else {

      int x1=x;          
      int y1=y;

  img.setRGB(x, y, color); 

 for (int i=0;i<img.getHeight();i++)  {
     for (int j=0;j<img.getWidth();j++){

         if (img.getRGB(x1+1, y1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()){
         x1++;
         img.setRGB(x1, y1, color);         
         }

         else if (img.getRGB(x1, y1+1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()){
         y1++;
         img.setRGB(x1, y1, color);          
         }      

         else if (img.getRGB(x1, y1-1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()){
         y1--;
         img.setRGB(x1, y1, color);     
         }

         else if (img.getRGB(x1-1, y1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()){
         x1--;
         img.setRGB(x1, y1, color);         
         }
}} 
}}
```

Comment: Would you please at least format that code?

Comment: You are using one single Color code. That would only be realistic in artificially made pictures. Even a conversion to jpeg and back will destroy this. You would rather want to give a threshold.

Comment: Then you should step it through in debugger. There are some issues with the index vars ...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it should work only for black and white pictures.

Comment: Maybe a better way to break the recursion would be to use a Point-List. Init it with the starting point. Then (loop) get point from list. Add to the list all the neighbors of that Point if: they are not a border and not already in the list. Then do the same for the next point in the list until the list is empty. In that course you set the color of the actual point in question. That way all Points inside the border will once have been in the list and processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in increment and decrement the variables x1 and y1. For example, when `img.getRGB(x1+1, y1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()` is true and `img.getRGB(x1-1, y1)==Color.BLACK.getRGB()` is true you first increment x1 variable and next decrmenet so in next interation of for loop your x1 is the same as previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a different approach to avoid the error you are making with decrementing / incrementing your vars:

(Pseudo-Code!)

```
void floodfill( Image img, int startX, int startY, int borderColor )
{
     Point startPoint = new Point(startX,startY);
     if( !isNoBorder(startPoint, img, borderColor ) return;
     List<Point> workList = new ArrayList<Point>();
     workList.Add( startPoint );

     while( workList.size() > 0 )
     {
         Point p = workList.remove(0);
         Point p1 = new Point( p.X+1, p.Y );
         Point p2 = new Point( p.X-1, p.Y );
         Point p3 = new Point( p.X, p.Y+1 );
         Point p4 = new Point( p.X, p.Y-1 );
         if( isNoBorder(p1, img, borderColor) && !workList.contains( p1 ) ) workList.Add( p1 );
         // same for p2-4
         img.setRGB( p.X, p.Y, borderColor );
     }
}

boolean isNoBorder( Point p, Image img, int borderColor ){
    return p.X >= 0 && p.Y >= 0 && p.X < img.getWidth() && p.Y < img.getHeight() && img.getRGB(p.X,p.Y) != borderColor  ;
}
```